# AngularJS + Breeze + Security

Tags: angularjs, security, breeze

We are trying to use AngularJS with Breeze, with a .NET backend. We have gotten things hooked up working together. However, we are having trouble figuring out how to lock things down based on the user role and the user's own data.

Can anyone point us in the general direction? We couldn't find anything explicitly in Breeze's documention.

Comment: I assume when you say user role you mean lock things down on the backend?

Comment: Trying to nail down the scope of this question- How far along are you?  Do you have the user authentication piece taken care of?  In other words is the user logged-in and your ApiController's [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user) property has the current user's identity?

Comment: All data returned from the server needs to be locked down to the user that is requesting the information (unless it's not tied to a user). After authenticating you must use a token or session to link to a user and every query will only return data for that query by adding a filter in the where clause. Also you may also need to restrict some data to authenticated users which is not linked to a specific user. Then there could be public data that is available for the public which would need no restrictions

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We're basically bolting this on to an existing system which already has user authentication and all that. To clarify, we are looking for documentation on "how" to do this with Breeze. We understand the "what" of what we need to do.

Comment: What do you want Breeze to do? On the client? On the server?

Comment: @Ward: Sorry for the slow reply. We're hoping to use Breeze on the client side, if we can use it in a secure way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why Breeze should be insecure. Security is orthogonal. My question remains: what are your concerns?

### Update 2 March 2015

Thanks for the clarifying comment ... which reflects concerns that are widely share. I really am going to have to write about this at length in our documentation.

Fortunately, I believe I can ease your mind about the specific issues you raised.

BreezeJS, the client library, can only reach the data that your server allows the current user to access. It's the server's job to grant or refuse such requests.

This is fundamentally the same story for a client written with *any* technology talking to a server written with *any* technology. If the server has a "Customers" endpoint, than a client can request all of your customers and will receive them *unless you guard that endpoint* with logic on the server. This is true with or without Breeze.

You may be thinking that the metadata describes your entire database schema and therefore exposes the entire database to Breeze client requests. That statement is not true on a couple of counts.

First, even if the client knows about your entire database schema, it can't do anything with that knowledge unless you go to the trouble of exposing every table in your web api with unguarded endpoints. This is entirely within your control and its not something you can do by accident.

Second, there is no good reason to send metadata that describe your entire database. If you let the server generate the metadata based on the Entity Framework model, you can easily limit the size and shape of that model to the subset of the database that you want to expose in your client-facing api.

After you've narrowed the model and the web api to the size and shape appropriate for your application, you **must** take the next step ... the step you'd take for any web api imaginable ... which is to guard the endpoints.

At a minimum that means ensuring that the user is authenticated and authorized to make requests of each endpoint. But it also means preventing unwanted responses even to authorized user requests. For example, you might want to limit **on the server** the number of Customers that can be returned for any given customer query. You might want to throttle the number of requests that you'll process in a single interval of time. You might want to filter the customers down to just those few that the user is allowed to see.

The techniques for doing these things are all part of the ASP.NET Web API itself, having nothing to do with Breeze whatsoever. You'll want to investigate the options that Web API has to offer.

The update side of things is actually much easier to manage with Breeze components for ASP.NET Web API. The conventional Breeze update mechanism is a batch post to a single `SaveChanges` endpoint. In other words, the surface area of the attack can be limited to a single endpoint. The Breeze `SaveChanges` method for .NET offers two interception points for security and integrity checks:

1. **`BeforeSaveEntity`** where you can inspect and confirm every entity individually before it gets saved to the database.
2. **`BeforeSaveEntities`** where you can inspect the entire batch *as a whole* ... to ensure that the save request is cohesive and legitimate. This is something you can't do in a simple REST-ish api where PUT/POST/DELETE requests arrive as separate, autonomous events

The Breeze query language is highly expressive so it is possible that the client may query the server for something that you were not expecting. The `expand` clause is probably the most "dangerous" in this regard. Someone can query the Customer endpoint and get their related Orders, their related OrderDetails, the related Products, etc ... all at the same time.

That is a great power and with it comes responsibility. You may choose to withhold that power by refusing to allow `expand` queries. You can refuse `select` queries that can "expand" by selecting related entities. The ASP.NET Web API makes it easy to impose these restriction.

Alternatively, you can allow `expand` in some cases and not others. Or you can inspect the query request within the GET endpoint's implementation and refuse it if it fails your security checks.

You could decide that you don't want certain entity types to be "queryable" at all. You can create just the specialized GET endpoints you need to support safe access to those highly sensitive types. If the supporting methods don't return `IQueryable`, neither Breeze nor Web API will attempt to turn the OData query parameters into LINQ queries. These endpoints look and behave exactly like the traditional REST-ish apis that are familiar to you now.  And the Breeze client will be happy to play along. When you compose a Breeze query, the client doesn't know whether the server will honor that request. With Breeze you can compose any request you want and send it to any HTTP endpoint you desire. You're not limited to OData-style queries.

You don't need ONE approach for querying. You decide what entity types are exposed, how, and under what conditions. You can and should write the guard logic to ensure that the proper data are returned by a query or updated by a save ... just as you would for *any* web api. Both Breeze and Web API give you a rich set of tools for writing such guard logic. Your options are unbounded.

Finally, I observe that Breeze-oriented apis tend to be much smaller than the typical RESTy api ... that is, they offer fewer endpoints and (in this sense) a smaller surface area. As a practical matter, that means you can concentrate your server-side security budget on fewer methods and potentially improve both the quality of that code and your capacity to scrutinize your api's security risks.

Comment: As we understand it, Breeze basically opens up whatever schema we give it access to. In theory, this means that a malicious user could hack in (since it's all on the client-side) and make queries that we didn't directly intend. Since many parts of the schema are opened up, but should only be accessed for the authorized user, that's a concern. We're trying to figure out how to lock it down so only those who should access information, can.